# Как добавить дополнительные поля при сериализации dataclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть датаклассы наподобие таких:

```
@dataclass
class BaseItem:
    some_field: int

@dataclass
class ExtraItem(BaseItem):
    extra_field: str

@dataclass
class ExtraItem2(BaseItem):
    extra_field2: bool

@dataclass
class ItemsInfo:
    count: int
    items: List["BaseItem"]

item1 = ExtraItem(some_field=1, extra_field="foo")
item2 = ExtraItem2(some_field=2, extra_field2=True)

items_info = ItemsInfo(count=777, items=[item1, item2])
```

И я хочу сериализовать их в JSON с добавлением информации о типе, чтобы получить что-то такое:

```
{
  "count": 777,
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "extraitem",
      "some_field": 1,
      "extra_field": "foo"
    },
    {
      "type": "extraitem2",
      "some_field": 2,
      "extra_field2": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Как можно реализовать подобное без добавления лишних мусорных полей в датаклассах?

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать `type` неинициализируемым полем, и задавать его значение в `__post__init__`

```py
@dataclass
class BaseItem:
    type: str = field(init=False)
    some_field: int

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.type = type(self).__name__.lower()
```

и тогда можно будет рекурсивно преобразовать `items_info` в `dict` с помощью `dataclasses.asdict`

```py
print(json.dumps(dataclasses.asdict(items_info), indent=2))
```

Либо можно реализовать собственный сабкласс `JSONEncoder`

```py
class MyJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, BaseItem):
            return dict({'type': type(obj).__name__.lower()}, **obj.__dict__)
        elif isinstance(obj, ItemsInfo):
            return obj.__dict__
        else:
            return super().default(obj)
```

```py
print(json.dumps(items_info, cls=MyJSONEncoder, indent=2))
```